# Resize after paintEvent generated content

Tags: qt, resize, dimensions, qt5, paintevent

How can I resize, automatically, any widget, to the paintEvent's method generated content dimensions?

Comment: I've not managed to do anything

Comment: I've used another QFontMetrics based on the current object font() to calculate the width externally from paintEvent

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't try to do that.  Resizing would generate a new paint event, and in the best case you would end up with flickering in your UI.  You will need to calculate your widget size outside the paint event.